# Julia: How you subtract a Normal distribution from a Chi distribution?

Tags: julia, distribution

Is there any to "subtract" a normal distribution from a Chi distribution? Julia gives the following error when simply subtracting:

```
MethodError: no method matching -(::Chi{Float64}, ::Normal{Float64})
```

In addition, the `convolve` function from Distributions.jl does not support convolving Chi distributions.

Comment: What result are you hoping to get from the operation? A new distribution? The vast majority of convolutions of distributions do not have closed form solutions, so defining a generic `convolve` across all distributions is not feasible without defining some sort of abstract distribution type that expresses non-closed forms. Given that the main purpose for such a form would just be sampling from that distribution my guess is that this sort of functionality should be in its own package. I haven't seen one that does this, but maybe ask on Discourse...

Comment: Also, Distributions.jl does support convolving chi-squares according to the docs, but only the convolution of two chi-squares. It does not support the convolution of chi-square and Normal (does this even have a closed form? I don't think it does although am not certain off the top of my head).

Comment: This question was already asked and discussed at length on the Julia Discourse [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-add-subtract-probability-distributions/75673), with the same points being made that Colin made above. I'm voting to close as this isn't a Julia question but a conceptual stats question, if you want to ask about arithmetic over probability distributions then Crossvalidated is probably the better place.